# racoon IPSec/L2TP Client

Tags: windows, vpn, ipsec

I am trying to configure a racoon IPSec/L2TP client to connect a Windows 2003 server. The server is originally intended to be used with Windows XP clients (successfully tested with Windows XP SP3 but it doesn't work with either XP SP1 or Windows 7). To complicate the matter even a bit more both pre-shared key and x509 certificates are used at the same time.
I deduced the following from the working client and tried to replicate the configuration on racoon:

- No NAT-T (It is dropped since Windows XP SP2)
- No `tunneling mode` (Windows XP does not support it)
- No `AH` (Windows XP does not support it)
- `3des` for encryption algorithm
- `sha1` for hash algorithm
- `dh_group 2`
- I am not sure about authentication mode and tried both `pre_shared_key` and `rsasig`

My `racoon.conf`:

```
log debug2;

path certificate "/home/ipsec/out/etc/certs";
path pre_shared_key "/etc/psk.txt";
path script "/etc/racoon/scripts";

remote 10.0.1.2 {

       exchange_mode main;

       my_identifier user_fqdn "user@example.com";
       certificate_type x509 "client.example.crt" "client.example.key";
       ca_type x509 "ca.crt";

       passive off;
       generate_policy on;
       dpd_delay 20;
       proposal {
               encryption_algorithm 3des;
               hash_algorithm sha1;
               authentication_method pre_shared_key;
               dh_group 2;
       }
}

sainfo anonymous {
        encryption_algorithm 3des;
        authentication_algorithm hmac_sha1;
        compression_algorithm deflate;
}
```

My `setkey.conf`

```
# Flush the SAD and SPD
flush;
spdflush;


spdadd 0.0.0.0/0 vpn.example.com[1701] any -P out ipsec
        esp/transport//require;


spdadd vpn.example.com [1701] 0.0.0.0/0 any -P in ipsec
        esp/transport//require;
```

I ran `setkey -f /etc/setkey.conf` then ran `racoon -F`. Following is my racoon log:

```
Foreground mode.
2015-07-18 17:25:25: INFO: @(#)ipsec-tools 0.8.2 (http://ipsec-tools.sourceforge.net)
2015-07-18 17:25:25: INFO: @(#)This product linked OpenSSL 1.0.0a 1 Jun 2010 (http://www.openssl.org/)
2015-07-18 17:25:25: INFO: Reading configuration from "/home/ipsec/out/etc/racoon.conf"
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: filename: /home/ipsec/out/etc/certs/client.example.crt
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: filename: /home/ipsec/out/etc/certs/ca.crt
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: lifetime = 28800
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: lifebyte = 0
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: encklen=0
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: p:1 t:1
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: 3DES-CBC(5)
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: SHA(2)
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: 1024-bit MODP group(2)
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: pre-shared key(1)
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: 
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: Etype mismatch: got 2, expected 4.
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: no check of compression algorithm; not supported in sadb message.
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: getsainfo params: loc='ANONYMOUS' rmt='ANONYMOUS' peer='NULL' client='NULL' id=0
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: parse successed.
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: open /home/ipsec/out/var/racoon/racoon.sock as racoon management.
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: Netlink: address 192.168.110.57 added
2015-07-18 17:25:26: INFO: 192.168.110.57[500] used as isakmp port (fd=7)
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: Netlink: address 127.0.0.1 added
2015-07-18 17:25:26: INFO: 127.0.0.1[500] used as isakmp port (fd=8)
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: Netlink: address 127.0.0.0 added
2015-07-18 17:25:26: INFO: 127.0.0.0[500] used as isakmp port (fd=9)
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: pk_recv: retry[0] recv() 
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: got pfkey X_SPDDUMP message
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: 
02120000 18000100 01000000 2d0d0000 03000500 ff200000 020006a5 d401c161
00000000 00000000 03000600 ff000000 02000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000300 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000400 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000200 00000000 00000000 00000000 4a10aa55 00000000 00000000 00000000
04001200 02000300 7a010000 00000080 10003200 01020000 00000000 00000000
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: pk_recv: retry[0] recv() 
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: got pfkey X_SPDDUMP message
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: 
02120000 18000100 02000000 2d0d0000 03000500 ff200000 020006a5 d401c161
00000000 00000000 03000600 ff000000 02000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000300 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000400 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000200 00000000 00000000 00000000 4a10aa55 00000000 00000000 00000000
04001200 02000100 70010000 00000080 10003200 01020000 00000000 00000000
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=in
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x97e00: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=fwd
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: pk_recv: retry[0] recv() 
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: got pfkey X_SPDDUMP message
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: 
02120000 18000100 03000000 2d0d0000 03000500 ff000000 02000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 03000600 ff200000 020006a5 d401c161 00000000 00000000
04000300 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000400 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000200 00000000 00000000 00000000 4410aa55 00000000 00000000 00000000
04001200 02000200 69010000 00000080 10003200 01020000 00000000 00000000
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 10.0.1.2/32[1701] proto=any dir=out
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x97e00: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=fwd
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 10.0.1.2/32[1701] proto=any dir=out
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x9cc20: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=in
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: pk_recv: retry[0] recv() 
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: got pfkey X_SPDDUMP message
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: 
02120000 16000100 04000000 2d0d0000 03000500 ff000000 02000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 03000600 ff000000 02000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000300 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000400 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000200 00000000 00000000 00000000 4201aa55 00000000 00000000 00000000
02001200 01000500 2c000000 00000000
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=5
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x97e00: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=fwd
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=5
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x9cc20: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=in
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=5
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x9df28: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 10.0.1.2/32[1701] proto=any dir=out
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: pk_recv: retry[0] recv() 
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: got pfkey X_SPDDUMP message
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: 
02120000 16000100 05000000 2d0d0000 03000500 ff000000 02000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 03000600 ff000000 02000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000300 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000400 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000200 00000000 00000000 00000000 4201aa55 00000000 00000000 00000000
02001200 01000400 23000000 00000000
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=4
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x97e00: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=fwd
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=4
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x9cc20: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=in
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=4
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x9df28: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 10.0.1.2/32[1701] proto=any dir=out
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: pk_recv: retry[0] recv() 
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: got pfkey X_SPDDUMP message
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: 
02120000 16000100 06000000 2d0d0000 03000500 ff000000 02000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 03000600 ff000000 02000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000300 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000400 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000200 00000000 00000000 00000000 4201aa55 00000000 00000000 00000000
02001200 01000500 1c000000 00000000
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=5
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x97e00: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=fwd
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=5
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x9cc20: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=in
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=5
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x9df28: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 10.0.1.2/32[1701] proto=any dir=out
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: pk_recv: retry[0] recv() 
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: got pfkey X_SPDDUMP message
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: 
02120000 16000100 07000000 2d0d0000 03000500 ff000000 02000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 03000600 ff000000 02000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000300 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000400 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000200 00000000 00000000 00000000 4201aa55 00000000 00000000 00000000
02001200 01000400 13000000 00000000
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=4
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x97e00: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=fwd
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=4
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x9cc20: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=in
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=4
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: db :0x9df28: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 10.0.1.2/32[1701] proto=any dir=out
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: pk_recv: retry[0] recv() 
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG: got pfkey X_SPDDUMP message
2015-07-18 17:25:26: DEBUG2: 
02120000 16000100 08000000 2d0d0000 03000500 ff000000 02000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 03000600 ff000000 02000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000300 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000400 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000200 00000000 00000000 00000000 4201aa55 00000000 00000000 00000000
02001200 01000500 0c000000 00000000
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=5
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG: db :0x97e00: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=fwd
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=5
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG: db :0x9cc20: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=in
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=5
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG: db :0x9df28: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 10.0.1.2/32[1701] proto=any dir=out
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG: pk_recv: retry[0] recv() 
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG: got pfkey X_SPDDUMP message
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG2: 
02120000 16000100 00000000 2d0d0000 03000500 ff000000 02000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 03000600 ff000000 02000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000300 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000400 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04000200 00000000 00000000 00000000 4201aa55 00000000 00000000 00000000
02001200 01000400 03000000 00000000
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=4
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG: db :0x97e00: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=fwd
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=4
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG: db :0x9cc20: 10.0.1.2/32[1701] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=in
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG: sub:0xbe9ca868: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 0.0.0.0/0[0] proto=any dir=4
2015-07-18 17:25:27: DEBUG: db :0x9df28: 0.0.0.0/0[0] 10.0.1.2/32[1701] proto=any dir=out
```

After this no traffic passes through the established vpn (I am even not sure whether a connection is established) and `setkey -D` reports no SAD.

**EDIT:**

I found that the main problem is *routing*. While L2TP mode is `transport` here, the server should act as a gateway for the network behind server but no traffic passes through l2tp to the server. Therefore the tunnel does not get initiated. I tried to add a route but was not successful.

Comment: What do you get when you do a traceroute to an address in the remote subnet? Maybe the tunnel does not get initiated?

Comment: @aairey I found that main problem is routing. The server should act as gateway for the network behind server but no traffic passes through l2tp to the server. Therefor, as you mentioned, the tunnel does not get initiated.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts :) Great news that you found the issue!